# Selenium crashes after loading Chrome profile using Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a very simple code that specifies a Chrome profile:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Users/johnh/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 4)

while(True):
pass
```

When I run my code, the browser opens with the Chrome profile 2 that was specified, but the terminal shows an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\johnh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\comprehend\main.py", line 16, in <module>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\johnh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__     super().__init__(   File "C:\Users\johnh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__     super().__init__(   File "C:\Users\johnh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__     self.start_session(capabilities)   File "C:\Users\johnh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\johnh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\johnh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.   (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Stacktrace:    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7135F8EF2+54786]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713565612]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71341A64B]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7134494A6]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7134453BE]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713483FBB]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713483A30]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71347BC43]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713450941]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF713451B84]    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713947F52+3524194]  GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF71399D800+3874576]  GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713995D7F+3843215]  GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF713695086+694166]   (No symbol) [0x00007FF713570A88]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71356CA94]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71356CBC2]    (No symbol) [0x00007FF71355CC83]    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFDEFF5257D+29]     RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDF190AA78+40]
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Tried specifying the chromedriver PATH:

```
PATH = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe

# Create a service object with the executable path

service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(PATH)

# Start the service

service.start()

# Create a driver using the service and options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

But the result was the same.

Comment: Solved this by making a copy of the User Data folder